# NSData(contentsOfFile: "someexistingfile") returns nil in Playground

Tags: file, swift, nsdata, swift-playground

Is there a good reason that above returns nil in Playground? When run in AppDelegate the statements returns the file contents, but in Playground it's nil. Is it just another silly bug from Apple? Or just me not finding the docu which states that this is not allowed?

Comment: Do you specify an absolute path to the file?  If not, you can use `let myPath = NSFileManager.defaultManager().currentDirectoryPath` to see the default location while you're in the playground.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out that Playground was simply unwilling. Booo, Apple. I used the command

```
rm -rf "$(getconf DARWIN_USER_CACHE_DIR)/org.llvm.clang/ModuleCache"
```

to get it going once again. A receipt I learned somewhere else on SO. This also cures a lot of other unwillingnesses of XCode.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a playground example where I have created a file called "test" at the reported path:

```
let myPath = NSFileManager.defaultManager().currentDirectoryPath
let theData = NSData(contentsOfFile: "test")
let aString = NSString(data: theData!, encoding:4)
```

It displays...

> "/Users/phil/Library/Containers/com.apple.dt.playground.stub.OSX.MyPlayground-C3A89455-96BA-4D37-A079-5893ED07EC92/Data"
>
> {NSConcreteData}
>
> {Some "Some text\n\n"}

...as the generated results.

Comment: Thanks for trying it. But as said, NSData gave nil. I finally figured out that Playground hat hick-ups. See my own answer.

Comment: My intent was to demonstrate (for myself, if no one else) that it was a valid thing to do.

Comment: I know and appreciate that. Finally that got me restarting XCode as I described in my answer. XCode as it is: still a PITA :-(